# How to get the runtime ID in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp.net elements  when page is run 
it changes its ID dynamically to add  "ctl00_Content" to the ID 
I tried to call the ID element in this way to avoid this dynamic name

```
$("#<%=btnCreate.ClientID%>")
```

but when the page add  "ctl00_" only I tried to write it as 
"#ctl00_MyActionMenuControl_btnCreateNew" and it works well 
but when I try to write it as 
`$("#<%=MyActionMenuControl_btnCreateNew.ClientID%>")` gives me error

please help

Comment: you should use `ClientIDMode="static"` on your aspx controls, so you'll have Id's with prefix.

Comment: What error does it give you? It could be because of the bad tag formatting. Instead make sure to output the whole string from the C# code like this: `$('<%="#" + MyActionMenuControl_btnCreateNew.ClientID%>')`

Comment: What is wrong with this $("#<%=btnCreate.ClientID%>") it would work

Answer (score 1):

> One way to do this as follows

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCreate" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

> Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = $("#btnCreate");
    var btnText = $("#btnCreate").text();
    alert(btnText);
</script>
```

> But in your case change your code as follows, it will work fine

```
$("#"+'<%=MyActionMenuControl_btnCreateNew.ClientID%>')
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting just a bunch of code with "Try this" or similar. Add some explanation as to what is the OP's problem and how your code resolves it

Answer (score -2):

mziaulhaq  was right.
If you try to use server controls into client side validation/in funcationality you must use 'ClientIDMode="Static"'. It helps you to maintain the ID as Static even though it was server side control.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnCreate" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```